# I am trying to use cout, i get this message no operator ">>" matches these operands

Tags: iostream, cout

I am getting the error message "no operator ">>" matches these operands".

-In the code I include the header file iostream.

-I delcare that i am using the formatting(?not sure if that's correct way to state) using namespace std).

-I make room for the variable using an assignment operator.

-I then use the insert num1 to be output with the stream insertion operator.

can someone please tell me where I went wrong.

why is the stream insertion operator not being recognized. the >> is underlined with a red squiggly line in my ide. I am using visual studio 2019 if that makes a difference.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()    
{    
    int num1 = 1;   
    cout >> num1;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout  <<  num1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been awhile. You are using the wrong operator. `>>` is used with the `cin` object to read but `<<` is used with `cout` to write:

```
cout << num1;
```